# Why does the Jama matrix inner dimension agree in the first iteration, but later it does not?

Tags: android, android-studio, matrix, matrix-multiplication, jama

Following `Jama` Matrices are defined in my code:

```
P: 3*3 Matrix
I: 3*3 identity Matrix
K: 3*2 Matrix
H: 2*3 Matrix
Q: 3*3 Matrix
```

Following is my code snippet:

```
private Matrix getP() {
        P= (I.minus(K.times(H))).times(Q);
        Log.d("csv", "P is calculated");
        return P;
    }
```

While running the code, at first iteration it works, i.e, `P is calculated` is printed at the Logcat. However, it happens only once and the application gets stopped. Following is the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matrix inner dimensions must agree.
```

If the Matrix inner dimension was the error, how come it runs for the first iteration? I obtained some information about the inner dimension at [this](https://github.com/fiji/Jama/blob/master/src/main/java/Jama/Matrix.java) link. However, I could not figure out the solution. When the equation is manually checked, the matrix dimension matches. 
Anything wrong with my approach??

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mind showing how you are calling `getP`? The following works no matter how many times I click on the `fab` button.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val I = Matrix.identity(3,3)
    val K = Matrix(3,2,5.0)
    val H = Matrix(2,3,7.0)
    val Q = Matrix(3,3,8.0)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            getP()
        }
    }

    private fun getP():Matrix{
        val P = (I.minus(K.times(H))).times(Q)
        Log.d("MainActivity","P is calculated")
        return P
    }
}
```

When `getP` returns where are you storing the results? Are you possibly overwriting one of the matrices?

**Update**

If your situation is such that making the variables final is not an option for you, then you can log each matrix's dimension and then debug the one that changes.

```
private fun getP():Matrix{
    Log.d(TAG,"I dimension: ${I.rowDimension} x ${I.columnDimension}")
    Log.d(TAG,"K dimension: ${K.rowDimension} x ${K.columnDimension}")
    Log.d(TAG,"H dimension: ${H.rowDimension} x ${H.columnDimension}")
    Log.d(TAG,"Q dimension: ${Q.rowDimension} x ${Q.columnDimension}")

    val P = (I.minus(K.times(H))).times(Q)
    Log.d(TAG,"P is calculated")
    return P
}
```

Comment: try declaring your matrices as final variables. And if you are overwriting them somewhere, you will know.

Comment: The main cause of the problem was overwriting. Although `getP` is a private method, it is called from a public method which itself was called from the next MainActicity class (multiple times). The clue `overwriting` helped me a lot.