# How to reset or flush the Jama Matrix in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, matrix, jama

I need to reset or flush the Jama Matrix before overwriting it to prevent the following error (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625085/why-does-the-jama-matrix-inner-dimension-agree-in-the-first-iteration-but-later)).

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matrix inner dimensions must agree.
```

I could not find any way to flush the Jama Matrix. If there any way to do so? An approach is suggested [here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/Jama.Matrix/reset) to use the following code.

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.reset();
```

However, it does not work. Any help, please!

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite/update a Jama Matrix in Android Studio without any error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59024375/how-to-overwrite-update-a-jama-matrix-in-android-studio-without-any-error)