# How to overwrite/update a Jama Matrix in Android Studio without any error?

Tags: android, android-studio, matrix, jama

Jama Matrices are defined in my code (*Matrix computation class*) as follows:

```
private Matrix A;
private Matrix B;
private Matrix C;
```

The matrix `A` is initialized as follows:

```
A = new Matrix(2,2);
A.set(0,0,1.5);
A.set(0,1,0.0);
A.set(1,0,0.0);
A.set(1,1,1.5);
```

Matrix `B` is a 2*2 matrix, initialized as an identity matrix and is updated every second by the next matrix of the same size from the `MainActivity` class.

Matrix `C` is initialized and computed as follows:

```
 if(C!=null)
 C = A.plus(C.times(B));
 else {
 C = new Matrix(2,2);
 C.set(0,0,1);
 C.set(0,1,0.0);
 C.set(1,0,0.0);
 C.set(1,1,1);
```

Here, the *Matrix computation class* is called by the *MainActivity class* every second and matrix `B` is updated accordingly. However, the code runs well for only the first iteration and throws an error in later as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matrix inner dimensions must agree.
```

After some digging, I found that it is caused due to **matrix overwriting** (Matrix `B` and `C`). The matrices in my code cannot be `static` or `final`. Is there any way to use the Jama matrix when the matrices are not static? Are there any alternatives to Jama in the android studio for Matrix operation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the matrix being static or final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code provided with JAMA, the IllegalArgumentException is thrown at that place:

```
   /** Linear algebraic matrix multiplication, A * B
   @param B    another matrix
   @return     Matrix product, A * B
   @exception  IllegalArgumentException Matrix inner dimensions must agree.
   */

   public Matrix times (Matrix B) {
      if (B.m != n) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix inner dimensions must agree.");
      }
      Matrix X = new Matrix(m,B.n);
      double[][] C = X.getArray();
      double[] Bcolj = new double[n];
      for (int j = 0; j < B.n; j++) {
         for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            Bcolj[k] = B.A[k][j];
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            double[] Arowi = A[i];
            double s = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
               s += Arowi[k]*Bcolj[k];
            }
            C[i][j] = s;
         }
      }
      return X;
   }
```

So appearently `C.times(B)` fails, which means that `C` and `B` dimensions do not agree. As we can also see from the line below, `C = new Matrix(2,2)` does have  2x2 size, which means that `B` must have a wrong size.

I do not understand what you mean with "matrix overwriting"? `C = A.plus(C.times(B))` does allocate a new instance of `Matrix` internally. This has nothing to do with `static` or `final`.

Please provide a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are many parts missing, like the place where B is initialized.